# AppStoreConnect ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bitcode

After uploading new app version to AppStoreConnect i receive error: Invalid Binary, alsa i receive email with more concrete error:

"TMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path."

I found an article describing how to identify a problem:
https://medium.com/360learning-engineering/resolving-itms-90562-invalid-bundle-email-from-the-app-store-d4a1030418e5

I go through the article, and according to the article everything is ok. So for version that we trying to upload for each **@rpath** we have proper **framework files**.

Do you have any idea what i should check more?